# Hiding code from end-user in the office

Tags: sql, vb.net, encryption, hide

I've got the following VB.NET code with SQL expressions:

```
SELECT 
    Period, 
    EmOrg, 
    ROUND(Sum(Total_H),2) As GrandTotal, 
    ROUND(Sum(FTE_O),1) As Division
FROM(
SELECT 
    LD.Period, 
    LD.EmOrg, 
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) AS 'Total_H', 
    Sum(LD.RegHrs)/176 AS 'FTE_O'
FROM SSI.dbo.LD LD
WHERE (LD.EmType In ('C','T','U')) AND (LD.EmOrg Like '%T00')
GROUP BY LD.Period, LD.EmOrg
UNION
SELECT 
    LD.Period, 
    LD.EmOrg, 
    Sum(LD.RegHrs) AS 'Total_H', 
    Sum(LD.RegHrs)/198 AS 'FTE_O'
FROM SSI.dbo.LD LD
WHERE (LD.EmType='S') AND (LD.EmOrg Like '%T00')
GROUP BY LD.Period, LD.EmOrg)AS counts
GROUP BY Period, EmOrg
```

How do I hide the code for end-users to use the functions of the code, but not edit or change values used in the code.

If this was VB.NET I would use (e.g) Button1.Enabled=False this deactivates the button
So in SQL what should I do to hide this code from users?

Answer (score 0):

Encryption of this code does not really protect you as it would constitute implementing some kind of DRM.

The best method of hiding the code is to put it on a (virtual?) server with strict access conditions, and making the function only available through e.g. a web service.